# TileVector - Possibility of an loadend event

Tags: openlayers-3

I try to figure out how to implement a load/error/start/end event for the requesting vector tiles to know if the layer is still requesting tiles or not (similiar to [tile events example][1]http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/examples/tile-load-events.html?q=tile+events) . Right now, the only possibility to get layerstate information on a TileVector is to catch the change event, which i think respond to the render event. Please let me know if you think its possible and i can implement some kind of custom event with not too much efforts or if its nearly impossible.

Comment: [Is this your case?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/99702/how-would-i-get-number-of-tiles-loaded-and-total-number-loading/141124#141124)

Comment: No, regarding the documentation [ol3-tileWMS](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/apidoc/ol.source.TileWMS.html) these events are only available for TileWMS not for TileVectors